# Ubuntu перестала видеть USB-модем

Tags: ubuntu, usb, модемы

Около 2 лет использую (якобы) МТС, а на самом деле - Huawei USB-модем.
Всё было замечательно до 7 марта  Дата здесь (похоже) важна.

Придя на работу утром и воткнув модем в USB разъём, я обнаружил, что
устройство распознаётся НЕ как модем, а как обычный флэш-накопитель.
Повторные попытки (в разные USB разъёмы, после перезагрузки...) ни к
чему не привели - Ubuntu его в упор не видела в качестве модема.

Устройство исправно - под виндой и дома, под OpenSuse - работает
абсолютно нормально.

*Network Manager* модем не видит. При попытке добавить мобильное сетевое
устройство, в списке - пусто.

На USB шине устройство обнаруживается:

```
# lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
E353/E3131 (Mass storage mode)
```

При втыкании модема в разъём в dmesg идёт такая выдача:

```
[ 4292.667606] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-
pci
[ 4292.801421] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1,
idProduct=1f01
[ 4292.801434] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2,
SerialNumber=3
[ 4292.801442] usb 2-1: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[ 4292.801449] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[ 4292.801455] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[ 4292.834936] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4292.835464] scsi host11: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[ 4293.842190] scsi 11:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass
Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 4293.843674] scsi 11:0:0:1: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD
Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 4293.850227] sr 11:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[ 4293.850468] sr 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 4293.850620] sr 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[ 4293.851026] sd 11:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 4293.856700] sd 11:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 4296.544779] sr 11:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK
driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4296.544795] sr 11:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error
[current] 
[ 4296.544805] sr 11:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read
error
[ 4296.544815] sr 11:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 0f fe
00 00 02 00
[ 4296.544822] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr0,
sector 16376
[ 4296.564772] sr 11:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK
driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4296.564786] sr 11:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error
[current] 
[ 4296.564794] sr 11:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read
error
[ 4296.564804] sr 11:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 0f fe
00 00 02 00
[ 4296.564811] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr0,
sector 16376
[ 4296.564819] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 2047, async
page read
[ 4296.795657] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
[ 4296.804925] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
```

Т.е. присутствую сообщения об ошибках чтения. Но почему это не мешает
работе под виндой и в OpenSUSE ?!

Но и в Ubuntu, хотя и как флэш-накопитель, видится и в него можно зайти,
посмотреть каталоги.

Добавление строк устройства

```
# Huawei                                                                 
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="1f01", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

в файл  */lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules* ничего не дало.

Создание файла *12d1:1f01* в каталоге */etc/usb_modeswitch.d* с
содержанием:

```
MessageContent=«555342431234567824000000800008ff52444556434847310000000
0000000»
```

ситуацию не улучшило.

Ручная загрузка модуля ядра *usbserial* так же ничего не дала:

```
# modprobe usbserial
# lsmod | grep usb
usbserial              53248  0
usb_storage            73728  2 uas
usbhid                 53248  0
hid                   122880  2 hid_generic,usbhid
```

Поскольку наблюдается эта ситуация только в Ubuntu, начиная именно с 7
марта, предполагаю, что в это время произошёл некий апгрейд системы,
который и привёл к нарушению работы модема.

Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что:

**Mass storage mode**

Есть идеи?

Comment: А у убунту нет лога обновлений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась, когда я исправил содержимое файла  файла 12d1:1f01 в каталоге /etc/usb_modeswitch.d следующим образом:

> MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000a11062000000000000100000000000000"

Это строка конкретно для  модели Huawei E353, VendorID=0x12d1, ProductID=0x14db

Comment: Вы можете принять собственный ответ? А то потом Дух сообщества начнет поднимать тему снова.

Comment: Втыкал/вынимал модем, перезагружал комп... Всё прекрасно работает.  Грузить вручную модуль *usbserial* оказалось ненужным.

Comment: Это все замечательно) Только галочку поставьте ответу, вдруг кому-то пригодится в дальнейшем

Comment: @DaemonHK, галочку на свой ответ можно поставить только через два дня после создания вопроса.

Comment: @mymedia когда плохо знаешь правила)) спасибо что просветили